# How to add column data as listbox items using access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to add table column data as listbox items, i tried to add table column names as list box items. But how do i add table column data as listbox items. 
I have a table

```
Column1

 A
 B
 C
 D
 E
```

I tried adding table column names as listbox items, vba

```
Sub item1() 

On Error Resume Next

Dim i As Integer 'Index for loop

    With Me.lstbox
        .RowSourceType = "Value List" 'Set rowsource type
        .RowSource = "" 'Clean combo contents
    End With

    For i = 1 To CurrentDb.TableDefs("table1").Fields.Count
    Me.lstbox.AddItem (CurrentDb.TableDefs("table1").Fields(i -1).Name)

    Next i
     End with
End sub
```

How do i have A,B,C,D,E as listbox items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the combo RowSourceType to Table / Query and either use the table name or SQL for RowSource.

```
With Me.lstbox
    .RowSourceType = "Table/Query" 'Set rowsource type
    .RowSource = "Select Field1 From Table1"
End With
```

Make sure you set the correct Bound Column, Column Count and Columns Widths. For the most part, there is no need for code with listboxes, just use the property sheet. If you are new to MS Access it is often useful to use the wizards.